# AOP Spring aspect method not applied on target object

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

Have an Aspect class (@Aspect) which aspect methods are not running. 
This is because the target object (org.services.myService) is not in the component-scan list. **servlet-context.xml**:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.controllers" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

If add the package "org.services" then the pointcut **@Pointcut("within(org.services.myService")**  works.

Issue is can´t change component-scan in the servlet-context.xml:

The project has a separate applicationContext.xml to scan the services folder and there it has a component-scan.

> Adding aspectj-autoproxy after each component-scan seems not to work
>   as only finds beans(controllers) scanned in first component-scan

Also, the project will throw an error if I do a component-scan twice on the same folder (JBoss: 2 beans found for autowiring),and other reasons due of the project structure (mixture of XML to allow it running in JBoss and Jetty).

How can I make myService class available to the aspect class without updating context:component-scan ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each XML configuration file (application context and servlet context) needs to create the beans on which the aspect is created, and also the Aspect class. 
I was missing the latest one in the component-scan:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.services, org.aspects"/> 
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

Each XML that processes the aspect (aspectj-autoproxy) needs to have in the same scope all beans required. (in this case, created through component-scan).

Answer (score 0):

With spring-aop you can only apply advice to spring beans, so if you don't register your `myService` bean with spring, the advice will not be applied. The advice will only be applied to bean instances you obtain from the spring context.

If you can't change the component scan directive to include the package of that bean, you can still add a configuration class in one of the scanned packages to instantiate your `myService` and register it as a spring bean.

```
package org.controllers;

@Configuration
public class MyServiceConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyService myService() {
        return new MyService();
    }
}
```

Or with xml configuration into one of your spring xml configs:

```
<bean class="org.services.MyService" />
```

Comment: Have two XML (servlet-context.xml and applicationcontext.xml). in first one I add context-scan for controllers and second one for services. aspectj-autoproxy in servlet-context.xml finds the controllers but if add in both places (or just in applicationcontext.xml), won't find the service. seems the first component-scan has precedence. i need to instantiate that service together with other services in another component, separated from the component where I have the servlet-context, so can't have an exception and use java configuration just for that service. Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer with xml configuration of the bean.

Comment: unfortunately can´t change how the beans are instantiated. in servlet-context.xml, scan controller beans, and in applicationContext.xml (another component) scan all services beans. I added aspectj-autoproxy after each component-scan. But not finding the bean. Only finds beans from the first component-scan that seems to run (servlet-context.xml). But can´t instantiate that bean in that file. don´t know if that annotation can´t let you specify additional paths to scan beans (without creating them) or a way to, at run time, link the aspect once the bean is created.

Comment: Scan beans without creating them? What would that even mean? If you can't change your spring configuration, you should've stated these limitations in your question. It's unfair to expect people to solve your problems only to tell them that whatever solution they come up with is excluded because of limitations you didn't state in your question. Without including new beans in your spring context it's impossible to solve your issue.

Comment: beans are created. I mean I can´t change the order. The component-scan annotation in each XML creates a set of beans, can´t just scan/create this bean separately.  aspectj-autoproxy injects the aspect to the beans created so far. Was wondering if lazy-loading was suppported (wait till all bean sin all XML have been created, then inject the aspect)

Comment: I found problem though. My @Aspect class was needed in the component-scan too. I had in one XML but in another XML where I have included aspectj-autoprox, that class was not instantiated as it was not scanned.